# A way to persist the same/unique id generated for crypto.randomUUID in a user on nodeJS?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, local-storage, handlebars.js

I'm developing a web app where I need to give the user a unique ID for him, I searched and used the crypto module to generate UUID and it works, here is the code for that (I'm sending it with my res.render of products).

```
import Product from '../models/Products';
const crypto = require('crypto');

const getProducts = async (req, res) => {
  const products = await Product.find().lean();

  const idValueUser = crypto.randomUUID();
  console.log(idValueUser);

  res.render('products/products', { layout: 'products-lyt',
                                    products: products, 
                                    userId: idValueUser});
};


module.exports = getProducts;
```

I'm passing to handlebars file the userId by the render and in the javascript of the file I pass that Id to the local storage:

```
<div class="container-fluid products-container">
    <div class="products-columns">
        {{#each products}}
        {{> products-partial }}
        {{/each}}
    </div>
    
        <p id="awadetest">{{userId}}</p>
</div>

<script>
    var testeo = document.getElementById("awadetest").innerHTML;
    console.log(testeo);
    localStorage.setItem("test", testeo);
</script>
```

The Id pass correctly to the localStorage (which I'll send to the database by a form after) but the problem is that every time the user reload (make a petition to the page of products) the id change (logically) but I need a way to make that Id persist so I can identify the user after on the Database, someone knows a way to do that? or if exist a better way to identify the user that doesn't imply log in or use the IP, btw thanks

Comment: set cookies then https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

Comment: or have a look at browser fingerprinting. don't know about code ethics though

Comment: I'll try, I never worked with cookies but I gonna give them a shot, thx, I'll keep you up date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If is helpful for someone I let the solution what works for me (easier that i thought):

Basically is to made a validation on the local storage (or cookie, if you're using it) like this:

```
window.onload = function () {
    var testeo = document.getElementById("awadetest").innerHTML;
    
    if (localStorage.getItem("userId") == null){
        localStorage.setItem("userId", testeo);
    }
    else{
        return;
    }
}
```

With this easily the code can identify if the browser already have a userId (I tested on different browsers and it works, generate different codes for every browser). And if someone is on the same "problem" that me (identify users after in a shopping cart) you can add to your "form" that is sent to DB the userId taking it from the local storage, hope it helps someone